# How to generate mysql query from relations using via or viaTable relations

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have the following relations in yii2 model

```
public function getStreamsFormations()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(StreamsFormations::className(), ['stream_id' => 'id']);
        }
public function getFormations()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(Formations::className(), ['id' => 'formation_id'])->via('streamsFormations');
        }
```

How to create complete mysql query from the relation "`getFormations()`"?

I need it to use it some where else...

I used ...

```
$query = $model->getFormations()->createCommnad()->rawSql;
```

But it skipped the via relation tables from the query.

Comment: Can you please look at this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47990955/generate-mysql-query-from-relations-using-via-or-viatable-relations

Comment: i have much explain my question...

Answer (score 0):

Relations not have where condition !  they are just join 2 table to theme ! you have to put your condition in find() queries!
if you need more information  just let me know .

Comment: jafar set this answer as correct m if not let me know how to help you ?