# generate mysql query from relations using via or viaTable relations

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

consider the below example...

```
class Customers extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function getOrders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Orders::className(), ['customer_id' => 'id']);
    }
    public function getOrderItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderItems::className(), ['order_id' => 'id'])
                    ->via('orders');
    }
}
```

how i can generate any one of the follwing query from the `getOrderItems()` relation

```
SELECT * FROM `order-items`
LEFT JOIN `orders` ON `orders`.`id` = `order-items`.`order_id`
LEFT JOIN `customers` ON `customer`.`id` = `orders`.`customer_id`
```

OR

```
SELECT `order-items`.* FROM `order-items`,`orders`,`customers`
WHERE `customer`.`id` = `orders`.`customer_id` AND `orders`.`id` = `order-items`.`order_id`
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM `order-items` WHERE `order_id` IN(
    SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `customer_id` IN(
        SELECT * FROM `customers`
    )
)
```

i use the following code to do this.

```
$customers = Customers::findAll();
$query = $customers[0]->getOrderItems()->createCommand()->rawSql;
```

but it only generates

```
SELECT * FROM `order-items`
```

What to do...???

Comment: you really want to see the rawsql ?

Comment: you really want to see the rawsql ? 

yes
yes

Comment: can anyone tell me which other queries can be generate from the  getOrderItems() relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this :

```
$q = Customers::findAll()->innerJoinWith('orderItems')->createCommand()->rawSql;
```

you have to use relation  name like this not as function

Comment: kiamoz!! Great!!

Comment: You are the legend!